# Query from linked SQL Server returns error if it has a "dot" in the table name

Tags: sql-server

Selecting data from a linked SQL Server returns an error when there is a period in the name of the table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [LEGOSDB].[LegosDB].[dbo].[MY.Employees]
```

Results in the following error message.

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LEGOSDB" does not contain the table ""LegosDB"."dbo"."MY.Employees"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

It works fine when I run a query without a period in the table name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [LEGOSDB].[LegosDB].[dbo].[BankingInfo]
```

Comment: Are you certain that table actually exists and that its *schema* isn't `MY`?  *(Does `Select * From LegosDB.LegosDB.My.Employees` work?)*

Comment: dots in DB and table names isn't very common for this reason, so @Siyual is most likely correct.

Comment: My be you should just try `SELECT * FROM  [LEGOSDB].[MY.Employees]`. The errors reports about the table named `"LegosDB"."dbo"."MY.Employees"`

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing you can't query a linked server without the server name. And you can't omit the schema from a fully qualified table name. You can use [Table] or [schema].[Table] or [Server].[schema].[Table]

Comment: Siyuai is correct.  Thanks